# Mirror Mirror On The Board

Tags: chess, optimization, retrograde-analysis

Mirror mirror in the board
Decipher the riddle of this horde
How many moves to it, please?
To put my brain at ease!
Both sides help, follow their paths
The solution you must craft
Oh, and there is but one way
Good luck, now off and away!

**Andrej N. Kornilow Andriy Frolkin & Dmitri W. Pronkin, 5408 Die Schwalbe 97 02/1986
3. Preis**

[image]

**Hint**: Check the tags!

Answer (score 2):

There is one question in this poem riddle, and it is

> How many moves to it, please?
>
> > Both sides help, follow their paths
> >
> > > The solution you must craft
> > >
> > > > Oh, and there is but one way

which I think it means

> How many moves leading to checkmate

and

I think this is the answer:
[lichess analysis](https://lichess.org/analysis/1b4N1/p2pp2p/1pprkpnQ/4r2p/4R2P/1PPRKPNq/P2PP2P/1B4n1_w_-_-_0_1#0)

21 moves, white forces moves to lead to a checkmate, taking advantage of the mirrored version.

Please tell me if this is the answer.

Comment: Sorry, it is not about checkmate. I have added in a missing tag.

Comment: okay, hmmmmmmmm